# How to increase the dedicated video memory

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios, vram

I was trying to play a 3D game (which requires very little video memory to run smoothly) on my laptop, it kept saying that we are running out of video memory. It is a Samsung Galaxy Book pro 360. It has more than 4000MB of graphics memory available but there is only 128MB of dedicated video memory. I have looked into the BIOS system but there was not anything like video setting or memory setting in the "advanced" category. The BIOS system is Samsung's

Could anyone suggest how to allocate more graphics memory to use?

In case if needed, this is the adapter information.

Chip Type: Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics Family

DAC Type: Internal

Adapter String: Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics

BIOS Information: Intel Video BIOS

Total Available Graphics Memory: 4060MB

Dedicated Video Memory: 128MB

System Video Memory: 0MB

Shared System Memory: 3932MB

Comment: You cannot;  You have shared all the maximum amount of memory supported by the iGPU. You do NOT have more than 4GB of VRAM you have more 4GB of system memory.  The iGPU in your system cannot be allocated more than 4GB of system memory.